# Change the loglevel of GoogleTagManager v5 on iOS

Tags: ios, analytics, google-tag-manager

I've integrated GoogleTagManager v5 in an iOS project. It's working fine, but now I see these logmessages in the Xcode console:

```
2017-07-14 09:09:19.285 App[23194:15302685] GoogleTagManager info: Loading container: GTM-XXX
2017-07-14 09:09:19.286 App[23194:15302665] GoogleTagManager info: Attempting to load saved version of container GTM-XXX
2017-07-14 09:09:19.310 App[23194:15302665] GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: gtm.load with parameters: (null)
2017-07-14 09:09:19.324 App[23194:15302665] GoogleTagManager info: Sending universal analytics hit: {
    "&t" = screenview;
    "&tid" = "UA-000000-1";
}
[...]
```

To reduce the amount of clutter in my console would like to change the loglevel for GoogleTagManager to warnings and errors only, but I can't find how to do this?

I've tried:

- Setting `GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel` but that doesn't have effect on these logs.
- Setting `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel` does silence Firebase logs, but not these GoogleTagManager logs.
- Passing the `-FIRAnalyticsDebugDisabled` argument also doesn't have effect on GoogleTagManager logs.
- Searched for pointers in the `GoogleTagManager.h` file, but there only seems to be one protocol in the TagManager CocoaPod since v5. So no logging options there.

Any ideas on how to change the Google Tag Manager log level or how to disable logging entirely?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? It's highly annoying.

Comment: @Wilmar No, I haven't solved this yet, it is annoying indeed I hope someone will come up with an answer. Feel free to up vote the question to let everybody know it also is of interest for you.

Comment: all the spam on GTM is making my console useless now

Comment: A year later and I'm still having this issue... Does anyone have suggestions? Does this happen on Android too?

Answer (score 4):

The only answer that I was able to find is a dark magic with swizzling:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411324/1016656